Getting error anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present in Sitecore Forms when Sitecore hosted on Azure FrontDoor
We are working on Azure PaaS environment for Sitecore XP 10.3. We are encountering one of the issue while submitting Sitecore forms.

The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not
present.

FYI, our application runs behind Azure Frontdoor with caching checked. So Publicly We have exposed the frontdoor URL to end users.
However, if we tried to run the forms with an internal URL, everything works as expected.
I have checked Sitecore Form __RequestVerificationToken cookie missing this solution, but it is not the case with our solution. Our forms rendering is not cached separately.

Check if the parent container rendering that holds this form rendering also doesn't have cache enabled.

We had a similar kind of issue for the 10.3 environment as well.
We noticed that it was related to parent rendering caching that has a placeholder to hold the form.
Check if you have caching enabled on parent rendering, if yes then uncheck caching and try again.
For reference: https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2024/02/27/sitecore-forms-object-moved-to-here/
